# UDP to TCP Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, packet

I am trying to figure out how to make this piece of code into TCP instead of UDP

```
DatagramPacket answerDP = null;
answerDP = new DatagramPacket(new byte[110], 110);
```

What do I use in TCP instead of `DatagramPacket`?

The same goes for `DatagramSocket`, what do I use in TCP instead?

```
DatagramSocket socket = null;    
socket = new DatagramSocket(); 
socket.send(packet);
socket.setSoTimeout(5000); //wait for answar max. 1 sec.
socket.receive(answerDP);
```

Comment: Are you the server or the client?

Comment: I am the Client.

Comment: Datagram is a big clue that you're looking at the wrong class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DatagramSocket` in TCP is basically `ServerSocket`

So for example, to initialise it:

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
```

And the client socket would be something like:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
```

Set timeout works the same

```
socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
```

See a simple example [here](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)

Comment: This may help: https://phoenix.goucher.edu/~kelliher/s2011/cs325/feb25.html